# Angular get nested element event in parent

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive

I am using Angular 4.
Consider the following component structure

```
<parent>

 <page>
    <content>
      <list>1</list>
      <list>2</list>
      <list>.</list>
      <list>.</list>
      <list>n</list>
    </content>
 </page>

</parent >
```

Here I want to be notified on the parent when any child page is scrolled.

Here I am showing only one page. There can be multiple pages here.

How should I go about doing this. Please point me in the right direction.

Thanks

Comment: `<page (scroll)="doSomething()">`?

Comment: @JBNizet yes that is on the page component. How can I get the scroll event of the page on the parent component.

Comment: emit an event from an Output. https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-listens-for-child-event

Comment: I tried that but the framework (ionic) does not have @output on the tabs component. Using the eventEmmiter solves this issue for now.

Answer (score 0):

Basic idea is you create a directive in the container of the Child page, and in container you listen for the 'scroll' event.

Then you dispatch the event (You can create your custom event dispatcher or you can use angular broadcast...). In parent page, you just set a listener for that event should be ok.